# How to create a has_many relationship record which won't error if the relationship record already exists in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have the following Rails 5 models setup:

```
JobTitle
  has_many :job_title_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :job_title_skills

Skills
  has_many :job_title_skills
  has_many :job_titles, through: :job_title_skills

JobTitleSkills
  belongs_to :job_title
  belongs_to :skill
  validates :job_title_id, uniqueness: { scope: :skill_id }
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
skill1 = Skill.find_or_create_by(title: 'YYY')

job_titles = JobTitle.all
job_titles.each_with_index do |job_title, index|
  case job_title.title
  when "XXXXX"
    job_title.skills << skill1
  end
end
```

The above works fine the 1st time I run it, but once the record is already created in the database, the above errors w:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Job title has already been taken
```

How can I update the above so that << instead of creating, creates ONLY if the record does not already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job_title.job_title_skills.find_or_create_by(skill: skill)`